# Apache Flink enrichment

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a source of events that looks like this

```
class Event {
    String userName;
    String webPage;
}
```

I need to enrich my stream of events with the past web pages access of the user. (I have the information in a DB and I can use it as a Flink source )

```
class EventStats {
    String userName;
    Map<String,Integer> webPageCounters; 
}
```

How do I make sure that before I start the processing of Event Stream I will have enrichment data ready for me?
I do not want to do DB calls from inside my stream.

Answer (score -1):

It may be a struggle to do this with Flink tbh. The first idea that comes to mind is to do a db scan and create a separate stream when the job is started. That stream could be used for initialization and You could simply union that with actual  `EventStats` stream, but this is not currently possible due to [this issue.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-2491)
So, basically there are two solutions that can be used.

First one is quite simple, so if You are doing the join manually, You can keep the elements from `Event` stream, that do not have matching `EventStats`. If You receive `EventStats` You simply check if there is any `Event` matching that can be emitted. You probably should also have a logic that removes elements from state after some time if those are not matched.

The other solution is a little bit trickier, but also more elegant. So, basically You can implement custom operator that does implement `InputSelectable`, in a way that it first tries to consume everything from the `EventStats` and only after that it starts reading elements of `Event` Stream. There are some caveats with that, You can refer to the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/operators/InputSelectable.html) for more info. Also, note that `InputSelectable` was introduced in Flink 1.9.